# Replace a column value in a string delimiter using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string value in a column in a table  like

```
001|3880000005376|Personal ID| ||15-MAY-2006
```

and I want to replace the fourth value by another string value 'ABCDEF' , can it be possible by a single update or by PL/SQL program?

Comment: Please include the DB schema and what you have attempted so far

Comment: SELECT trim(regexp_substr(PROP_VAL, '[^|]+', 1, level)) str
                FROM (SELECT  '001|3880000005376|Personal ID| ||15-MAY-2006' PROP_VAL FROM DUAL)
              CONNECT BY instr(PROP_VAL, '|', 1, level - 1) > 0 i have to use a loop to replace the fourth value, can it be done by replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2  (select 1, '001|3880000005376|Personal ID| ||15-MAY-2006'   from dual union all
  3   select 2, '002|3880000005376|Personal ID|XXX||15-MAY-2007' from dual
  4  )
  5  select
  6    id,
  7    regexp_replace(col, '[^|]+', 'NEW STRING', 1, 4) result
  8  from test;

        ID RESULT
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
         1 001|3880000005376|Personal ID|NEW STRING||15-MAY-2006
         2 002|3880000005376|Personal ID|NEW STRING||15-MAY-2007

SQL>
```

It replaces 4th occurrence of the `'[^|]+'` pattern with a `NEW STRING` value.

Comment: thank for the quick response, what if i want to update the same table using the string.

Comment: You're welcome. You'd just *update* it, e.g. `update test set col = regexp_replace(col, '[^|]+', 'NEW STRING', 1, 4);`

Comment: No problem; I'm glad if it helped.